# Is Mathematica / the Wolfram language able to query LDAP databases?

Tags: databases

I looked through the Wolfram language pages on data access and also searched the site but found nothing.

Is it possible to query an LDAP database (actually MS Active Directory) using the Wolfram language?

Comment: AFAIK there is no built in function to directly do that. But of course you could use NETLink (probably the first thing to try when querying active directory) or JLink using accoring libraries. Another possibility would be to `Run` or `RunProcess` a commandline tool. There is also some low level network functionality (search for network in help browser) in newer versions which you could build own code on. But even for a "lightweight" protocol that is most probably more trouble than worth it...

Comment: Thanks for confirming this - with a product as big as Wolfram there is always a chance that I have missed something. :-)

Comment: of course the chance that I have missed something is not any smaller :-)